# How to Programatically check elements and add class in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an app where I am running ng-repeat to display information. I need to then add classes to some of the generated elements after an Ajax call has been made.

I could do this easily with jQuery but I'm trying to stick to Angular/jqlite.

The problem I'm having is that I can get the element, but not as an object that `addClass` works on.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
angular.forEach($(".tile"), function(tile){
    if(srv.free.indexOf(angular.element(tile.querySelector('.label')).text()) != -1){
       tile.addClass("free");
    }
});
```

The array `srv.free` contains a list of names, those name values are the same as the text value of the `div` with class `.label`, which is inside of `.tile`. So I need to loop through each `.tile`, check the text value of the child `.label` and if that text value is in the array `srv.free`, add the class `.free` to `.tile`.

The point I'm at, is that `addClass` is "undefined" because at this point, `tile` is just a string, not a jquery/jqlite object.

How do I add a class to that, or get to the object version?

**Update**

I have previously tried to use `ng-class` on the elements to update the class, but could not get them to update.

I have a service that has `free` in it, which is initially set to a blank array. After an Ajax call:

```
$http.get('/json/free.json').success(function(data){
        srv.free = data;
});
```

Then, in my controller I have:

```
$scope.gsrv = globalService;
```

and in my ng-repeat:

```
<div class="col-xs-3 col-md-2" ng-repeat="Tile in list.tiles">
        <div class="tile" id="{{$index}}" ng-class="{free:$.inArray(Tile.Name, gsrv.free)}" ng-click="main.changeView('/Tile/'+$index)">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/256" ng-src="{{Tile.Icon}}" ng-class="{dis:!Tile.Stats}">
        <div class="label">{{Tile.Name}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When that didn't work, I tried adding:

```
$scope.gsrv.free = globalService.free;
```

which did not change anything.

Comment: user ng-class on the element in the view.

Comment: I once heard, what also applies here, if you are using jQuery in your controllers, you do something wrong (following guidelines of using angular)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You state that the elemens are rendered in an `ng-repeat`. Therefore you can just use the [`ng-class` directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) to add a class based on some variable, something like the following:

```
<div ng-repeat="tile in tiles" 
     ng-class="{ free: tile.someVariable }"> // <-- adds a class 'free' when someVariable verifies to true
    <label>{{ tile.someVariable }}</label>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

You can add those variables to the tiles, after the ajax call:

```
$http.get('/json/free.json').success(function(data){
    setTilesFree(data);
});

var setTilesFree = function (free) {
    var tiles = $scope.list.tiles; // shortcut
    for (var i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++) {
        // If in 'free' array, set tile free = true
        // This will update the DOM from this tile, adding the class 'free'
        if (free.indexOf(tiles[i].Name) > -1) {
            tiles[i].free = true;
        } else {
            tiles[i].free = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your view:

```
<div ng-repeat="Tile in list.tiles">
    <div ng-class="{free: Tile.free}">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/256" ng-src="{{Tile.Icon}}" ng-class="{dis:!Tile.Stats}">
        <div class="label">{{Tile.Name}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dcvdqdkv/2/)

Comment: Yes, but since the array I am checking against is populate via an Ajax call, the elements are pre-populated before the array has any content.

Comment: That shouldn't matter, when you do the ajax call and assign the data to the tiles variable, angular catches this and updates the DOM according

Comment: Then I'm doing that part wrong, because it's not updating for me. I have a service that is holding some information, including the array. When it updates the ng-class does not work...

Comment: Then please include how you are assigning your data to the tiles variable

Comment: Updated my question with info on my ng-repeat /ng-class

Comment: Tiles is a static pre populate JSON object, and due to its structure I can't just tack on a variable like that. Though you have given me an idea to try.

Answer (score 0):

You can return empty array from `list` and `free` services and populate them later. Since Angular runs digest cycle after every `$http.get`, `$scope` will be properly updated and binding will work as expected. The most tricky thing is to populate the same existing array (initially returned by service) instead of creating new one every time. This is required, because controller function will not run again every time digest is running and therefore new array instance will not be assigned to the `$scope`. Here is on of the possible solutions:

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module('app',[]).
    factory('list', ['$http', function($http) {
      var tiles = [];
      return {
        getList: function() {
          if(!tiles.length) {
            $http.get('data.json').then(function(res) {
              res.data.forEach(function(item) {
                tiles.push(item);
              });
            });
          }
          return {
            tiles: tiles
          };
        }
      }
    }]).
    factory('free', ['$http', function($http) {
      var free = [];
      return {
        getFree: function() {
          if(!free.length) {
            $http.get('free.json').then(function(res) {
              res.data.forEach(function(item) {
                free.push(item);
              });
            });
          }
          return free;
        }
      }
    }]).
    controller('ctrl', ['$scope', 'list', 'free', function($scope, list, free){
      $scope.list = list.getList();
      $scope.free = free.getFree();
    }]);
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-xs-3 col-md-2" ng-repeat="Tile in list.tiles">
    <div class="tile" ng-class="{free: free.indexOf(Tile.Name) > -1}">
        <img ng-src="{{Tile.Icon}}" ng-class="{dis:!Tile.Stats}">
        <div class="label">{{Tile.Name}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Plunker**

http://plnkr.co/edit/UEWnexi3wVU6eLN1BW2b?p=preview

*Update:*

http://plnkr.co/edit/vOHkLyCHQFoWdqaix4pH?p=preview

(the same example with static pre-populated `list`, and also `service` instead of `factory`)

Comment: List is a static, pre populated JSON object that is included on page load. I then create free as an empty array in my service. However once I update that same variable via $http, the ng-class doesn't update. Running a console.log shows the variable being updated.

Comment: @sharf In code snippet you provided `srv.free = data;` makes an issue, since with this assignment you replace one instance of empty array with another instance of array which is not watched by Angular. You should use `srv.free.push(...)` to put all the received data into the same instance of array hold by `srv.free`.